# Characterizing Solutions to a System of Non-Linear Equations

Tags: probability, nonlinear-system

I have a system of equations of a form:

$$
\forall_{i \not = j} P_{ij} = a_i b_j \frac{c_i}{c_i + c_j}
$$

Where i and j iterate over some set of indexes, P are some given probabilities such that $\Sigma P_{ij} = 1$, and I want to find a set of solutions for a, b and c. Is there any useful way to characterize that set? Or even to show that the system has a solution? I am looking for any clue or starting point here.

Comment: Well, if your set of indices has $n$ indices, then there are exactly $3n$ parameters $a,b$ and $c$, but you are given $n(n-1)$ values of $P$. So, very likely, there are no solutions (for $n>4$). Do you, perhaps, know for sure that at least one solution exists?